Find name of equivalent packages: from Ubuntu to Alpine
Is there a way of finding the equivalent package from a list of Ubuntu packages, for Alpine?
I'm aware of repology, apt-file, the apt-cache, apk search, https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org and https://packages.ubuntu.com. My question is about an automated way of finding the equivalents, e.g., given a list of packages and determining the smallest list of equivent packages (yes yes I know this is NP-hard).
How do I find the equivalent Alpine package for each dependent Ubuntu package?
